# Can pandas split/merge columns based on patterns in their name?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split, multiple-columns, reshape

Can pandas split and/or merge columns, based on patterns in the column name? Here's a `DataFrame`:

```
    meas1_left  meas1_right  meas2_left  meas2_right
0            1            2           3            4
1            6            7           8            9
```

I'd like to turn the above data and this (I don't really care how the new frame is indexed):

```
    meas1  meas2  side
0       1      3  left
1       2      4  right
2       6      8  left
3       7      9  right
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first create `Multiindex` from columns by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
print (df)
  meas1       meas2      
   left right  left right
0     1     2     3     4
1     6     7     8     9
```

Then  [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) it:

```
print (df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index())
   index  meas1  meas2
0   left      1      3
1  right      2      4
2   left      6      8
3  right      7      9
```

And if need rename column `index` and change order of columns:

```
print (df.stack()
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={'index':'side'})[['meas1','meas2','side']])

   meas1  meas2   side
0      1      3   left
1      2      4  right
2      6      8   left
3      7      9  right
```

EDIT: `str` methods with `index` are implemented from [0.16.1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#string-methods-enhancements), if use older version try:

```
a = df.columns.to_series().str.split('_').apply(pd.Series)
tuples = list(zip(a.iloc[:,0], a.iloc[:,1]))
print (tuples)
[('meas1', 'left'), ('meas1', 'right'), ('meas2', 'left'), ('meas2', 'right')]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
print (df)
  meas1       meas2      
   left right  left right
0     1     2     3     4
1     6     7     8     9
```

Comment: The first line gives me `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'str'`

Comment: You need upgrade pandas, is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so.. is it possible in older versions?

Comment: I add another solution, but i use version `0.18.1`, so I cannot test it.

Comment: I'm using `0.15.0` and `Series.str.split` didn't get `expand` until `0.16.1`

Comment: It looks like need `return_type='frame'` - see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.split.html).

Comment: Yea, I find solution [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings), please check edit.

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much!