# Creating new columns from unique values across rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use unique values in a pandas column to generate a new set of column. Here's an example `DataFrame`:

```
    meas1  meas2  side  newindex
0       1      3     L         0
1       2      4     R         0
2       6      8     L         1
3       7      9     R         1
```

I'd like to "multiply" my measurement columns with my key columns to generate a `DafaFrame` that looks like this:

```
   meas1_L  meas1_R  meas2_L  meas2_R
0        1        2        3        4
1        6        7        8        9
```

Note it's essentially the inverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39390615/512652).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
# Perform the pivot.
df = df.pivot(index='newindex', columns='side').rename_axis(None)

# Format the columns.
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
```

The resulting output:

```
   meas1_L  meas1_R  meas2_L  meas2_R
0        1        2        3        4
1        6        7        8        9
```

Comment: Solid answer as always.  But I mostly got excited about `df.columns.map('_'.join)`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using [`groupby.prod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.prod.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['side', 'newindex']).prod().unstack(level=0)
df.columns = ['_'.join(c[0::]) for c in df.columns]

          meas1_L  meas1_R  meas2_L  meas2_R
newindex                                    
0               1        2        3        4
1               6        7        8        9
```